# Django model with a custom field that uses a database default

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-custom-field

I am trying to implement a subclass of IntegerField to use a default method on my Postgres database, rather than a django default method (I know this is a hot topic). In order to do so I've modified the following method on my custom field

```
    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
        return 'default'
```

However, when django executes the SQL statement it looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table ('default_column') VALUES ('default')
```

The insertion fails because the `default` keyword is surrounded by quotes. The following SQL statement works:

```
INSERT INTO my_table ('default_column') VALUES (default)
```

I've noticed that the problem is in the way django performs `cursor.execute` by passing the SQL statement and parameters separately, thus causing the `default` keyword to be surrounded by quotes.

I am trying to find a way to resolve this without re-writing the postgres backend

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs)

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs 

def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
    return AsIs('default')
```

should do it.